# Text GameObject reference to Prefab on spawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with assigning a text object to prefab. After the prefab is spawned the text object is gone. Been trying to assign as GameObject, but it can't convert to UI.Text

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentlife;
    GameObject enemySpawner;
    private float timePassed;

    public Text LifeNow;

    GameObject hpBar;

    Slider healthBar;

    private void Start()
    {
        enemySpawner = GameObject.FindWithTag("Spawner");
        currentlife = 12;

        hpBar = GameObject.FindWithTag("TagForSlider");
        healthBar = hpBar.GetComponent<Slider>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (currentlife <= 0)
        {
            this.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("death");
            GameObject.Find(gameObject.name + ("spawn point")).GetComponent<Respawn>().Death = true;
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timePassed >= 0.5)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
        healthBar.value = currentlife;

        LifeNow.text = "Health: " + currentlife;
    }
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentlife -= damage;
    }
}
```

Comment: *`After the prefab is spawned the text object is gone.`* What do you mean by this?

Comment: [link] (https://gyazo.com/45386cac68b2cb95f1850e7db9eec6f4)

Comment: Ok, but what was it assigned to *before* you spawned it? Just because a Text object exists somewhere doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: Text object is assigned to the original "enemy" , but when i't dies the spawner creates a new enemy using prefab that does not have the text object assigned. Would like to make a script, that checks if the box "Life Now" is empty, and if it is, then assign Text object.

Comment: Assign the field *to the prefab's own text field.* When you assign the prefab's field to a specific spawned instance, that reference is lost when that instance is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You have a public Text LifeNow variable. You need to get the text object of the prefab and assign it to the variable prior to updating the text using LifeNow.text

e.g. `LifeNow = PREFAB.GetComponent<Text>();`

I would have asked if you were doing this in a comment prior to giving this as an answer, however I do not have enough rep to post a comment as of yet.

Comment: Would like to have some kind of a code example on this action

Comment: The Unity website has documentation on how to achieve this. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-text.html

Comment: FYI: Getting a reference to the prefab's Text object won't help, you need to get a reference to the *instantiated clone's* Text object.